# Сноска в круглых скобках

Tags: скобки

Как правильно?

> Далека дорога твоя, далека, дика и пустынна. Эта даль и глушь не для слабых душ, далека дорога твоя. Эта даль и глушь не для слабых душ, далека дорога твоя. (Боярский, «Прерия».)

> Далека дорога твоя, далека, дика и пустынна. Эта даль и глушь не для слабых душ, далека дорога твоя. Эта даль и глушь не для слабых душ, далека дорога твоя (Боярский, «Прерия»).